# WordPress Plugin development and 404 error

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have created some custom pages for my plugin, also I have a form which is submitted from the front-end. But, when submit button of that form is pressed, it redirects me to 404 page. After updating permalinks to "post-name", it works but all I want is that the form submit should properly work no matter what sort of permalink is set at the settings.

Some help on this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try changing the permalinks back? This sounds like the changes needed a permalink flush in order to start working (changing the permalink structure flushes rewrite settings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use like this: `action="<?php echo get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'page-id' ) ) ?>"` in the front-end form. Caution: page must exist.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use the normal link while submitting yourwebsite.com/?p=2 format this will work irrespective of permalink structure

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For now,I tried using this one in the form action:  `action="<?php echo get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'page-slug' ) ) ?>"`. So would there be any problem in future? Thank you!

Comment: Would recommend using id as slug can be changed and may change. you can use get_permalink($ID) https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/

Comment: Thanks for pointing that. I will rather use ID. But my confusion is that I've used action for my form like this: `action="<?php echo get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'page-id' ) ) ?>"`. So, will there be any problem in future?

Comment: only if the page your looking for doesn't exist !